# Recover files in Windows deleted with Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Wanting to delete a symlink in WSL I accidentally included the -rf option, resulting in WSL deleting the underlying folder on my Windows partition.

Is there any way to recover my data?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a private folder with no backups, most likely no.

If it's a system folder, you can try dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth from a command line in the system disk or you can try an automatic repair with said disk.